# QGIS 3.10 PyQGIS . Snapping tolerance units (Equivalence pixels - length units)

Tags: snapping, pyqt5, tolerance

Lately I have been dealing with snappings in QGIS. I have been able, with help of people from this site, and also, having a look at other peoples plugins, to ensemble a small plugin with forms.

My question is regarding the units of snapping, my layers are spatialite layers in WGS84, the project units is meters, but I could not set snapping to project units, so that left me degrees or pixels, for the time being I set the tolerance to 10 pixels, but what I really wanted is to set the snapping tolerance to length units.

If I use decimals degrees, the number is very small and I could not entered it in the box of tolerance, the minimal tolerance in degrees would be equivalent to a big tolerance in meters.

So now I have to ask, how do I calculate the equivalence between pixels and meters? Are pixels fixed or zooming affects the size of the pixels?

Comment: You may find `iface.mapCanvas().mapUnitsPerPixel()` useful, though it will still be in degrees if your project is in WGS 84.

Comment: Thank you Matt, indeed this answer my question. If I zoom in, the mapsUnitsPerPixel() are smaller.